# WordpressPCL Iterate over retrieved posts

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, xamarin.forms

I have the current code to get posts. This code will retrieve 4 posts which have the tag_id "100"

```
using System;
using WordPressPCL;
using WordPressPCL.Utility;
using WordPressPCL.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WPapp.Views
{
    public partial class Home : ContentPage
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var client = new WordPressClient("https://www.example.com/wp-json/");

            var queryBuilder = new PostsQueryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.PerPage = 4;
            queryBuilder.Page = 1;
            queryBuilder.Tags = new int[] { 100 };
            var posts = client.Posts.Query(queryBuilder);

            foreach (Post item in posts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("post");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate over all the posts stored in the variable "posts"

How do I achieve this? And how do I access details such as the posts featured image, title, content, date/time, etc... (all the meta of the post)?

Comment: is your `foreach` not working?  What specific problem are you having with the code you've already written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this code:

```
var featuredPosts = GetFeaturedPosts();

foreach (var item in featuredPosts)
{
    //Content here
}
```

```
public static List<WordPressPCL.Models.Post> GetFeaturedPosts()
{
    List<WordPressPCL.Models.Post> posts = null;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var client = new WordPressClient("https://www.wpwebsite.com/wp-json/");
        var queryBuilder = new PostsQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.PerPage = 4;
        queryBuilder.Page = 1;
        queryBuilder.Tags = new int[] { 100 };
        var post_task = client.Posts.Query(queryBuilder);
        post_task.Wait();
        posts = post_task.Result.ToList();
    }).Wait();
    return posts;
}
```

And it now works